# Why does scala (1 to 1000).foreach throw an exception in this case?

Tags: scala

In the repl, this throws an exception and I don't know why.
I would really like to understand this.

```
scala> (1 until 10000).foreach("%s%s".format("asdf", "sdff"))
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.apply(StringLike.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString.apply(WrappedString.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:75)
```

Comment: `(1 until 10000).foreach(_ => "%s%s".format("asdf", "sdff"))` is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Treat code below as unwrapped pseudocode:

```
val str = "%s%s".format("asdf", "sdff")
// "asdfsdff" you see, only 8 characters
(1 until 10000).foreach(x => str.getCharAt(x))
```

Comment: In fact, `str.apply` is called and not `str.getCharAt`.

Answer (score 7):

`Strings` in scala can be used like functions from an index to the char at the given index:

```
val s: Int => Char = "abcd"
val c: Char = s(1)
```

This is a general mechanism in Scala where an object with an `apply` method can be treated like a function. The `apply` method for strings is defined in [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps).

The string "asdfsdff" is being passed to foreach, and each successive value in the range is being passed to the function. This throws an exception when the index reaches `8` since this is out of range.

Comment: To be clear, you can't treat just any object with an `apply` method as a function. There has to be an implicit conversion function in scope to be able to use it as such. Here, it's `implicit def wrapString(s: String): WrappedString` on `Predef`, since `WrappedString` inherits from `PartialFunction[Int, Char]`.

Comment: Om-nom-nom answered first so I'll give him the point. Thanks for answering - I upvoted.